# PDF Viewer Zoom in and Zoom out

Tags: java, android

i am facing problem

this is my code dependency i have added

```
 implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.5'
```

this is xml coding

```
 <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
    android:id="@+id/pdf_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    >


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pdf_progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="215dp" />

</com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView>
```

this is java coding

```
 public void setPDF(String asset,int pages)
{
    pdfView.fromAsset(asset).swipeHorizontal(true).onLoad(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void loadComplete(int nbPages)
        {
            pdfView.fitToWidth(0);   // Goto to specific page
            pdfView.setMinZoom(60);
            pdfView.setMidZoom(80);
            pdfView.setMaxZoom(100);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }).defaultPage(pages).enableAntialiasing(true).load();
}
```

in onCreate Method 
     ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.pdf_progressBar);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

```
    PDFView pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdf_view);


    setPDF("new_quran_downloaded.pdf",28);
```

now i want to embed Zoom in and Zoom out property